# Sencha CMD - Build Error: Mixed-Mode x-compile and microload markup is currently unsupported

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

I am trying to build my ExtJS 4.2 application and I am using Sencha Architect 3.1 and Sencha CMD 5.1.1.39 for the OSX.

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.bitfiction.com/extjs-4-2-production-app-build-with-sencha-cmd/) on how to build from the Terminal, and as expected, I got this error:

`com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Mixed-Mode x-compile and microload markup is currently unsupported`

Upon searching, I came upon [this thread from Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?273418-Mixed-Mode-x-compile-and-microload-markup-is-currently-unsupported/page2) discussing how to get around this error.

What I did next was to remove lines from my `app.json` file which originally looked like this:

```
{
   "name": "my_app_name",
   "requires": [],
   "id": "eceafdc4-45e6-4dc1-b51a-75af9b7887a6",
   "resources": [
      "resources/css/rowCSS.css",
      "resources/css/receiptGrid.css",
      "resources/css/propertyGrid.css",
      "resources/css/msgBox.css",
      "resources/css/popWindow.css",
      "resources/css/passwordPrompt.css",
      "resources/css/textStyles.css"
   ],
   "theme": "ext-theme-classic-3ea6533d-fc56-477c-9143-5085a431c7f3",
   "js": [
      {
         "path": "app.js",
         "bundle": true
      }
   ],
   "css": [
      {
         "path": "bootstrap.css",
         "bootstrap": true
      }
   ]
}
```

and removed the "css" and "resources" parts as suggested in the tutorial above. However, I still had the same error.

My `index.html` file looks as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>my_app_name</title>
    <!-- <x-compile> -->
        <!-- <x-bootstrap> -->
            <script src="ext/ext-dev.js"></script>
            <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
        <!-- </x-bootstrap> -->
        <script src="app/override/form/Panel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <!-- </x-compile> -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/rowCSS.css" id="child-row">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/receiptGrid.css" id="receiptGrid">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/propertyGrid.css" id="propertyGrid">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/msgBox.css" id="msgBox">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/popWindow.css" id="popWindow">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/passwordPrompt.css" id="passwordPrompt">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/textStyles.css" id="textStyles">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Upon reading the thread in the Sencha website, it seemed that I had to choose over the `app.json` and the `index.html` file. So I tried and deleted the "resources" and "css", contents first then the entire thing after, and attempted to build it but to no avail. I still got the error.

I'm really dumbfounded and I'm trying to build and publish my web application so that the user doesn't have to load a whole lot of ExtJS scripts, a good chunk of which are not of use anyway.

I'm also confused because both `index.html` and `app.json`(along with `app.js` and `app.json.meta`) seem to be auto be auto generated by Sencha Architect 3.1. It does not make sense for an IDE to generate files that will seem to conflict later on during the build and publish process.

Also, the Sencha Thread is already 8 years old. I don't know how to go about this beyond the tips provided there. What can I try next?

Comment: What does your index file look like, can you post please?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by downgrading to Sencha CMD 5.1.0.26 (which solved another issue with 5.1.1.39, see [1]) and removing the `js` and `css` parts completely:

```
{
   ...
   "theme": "ext-theme-classic-3ea6533d-fc56-477c-9143-5085a431c7f3"
}
```

And yes, its a shame how a product that costs so much is maintained so incredibly bad.

[1] https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?297673-Bug-Incorrect-encoding-on-concatenated-JS-file-in-Sencha-Cmd-5.1.1.39&p=1087279&viewfull=1#post1087279