# "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated" using nodejs app.get or http-server

Tags: node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, synchronous, httpserver

I am creating a front end in AngularJS for a backend in node.js.  I have the option of two simple node.js front end servers to serve the front end web page:  one is a simple app.get in express, the other is using the http-server package.

Whichever front end server code I use, I get the following browser console message in Chrome:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

To make sure that this was not caused by anything Angular (or Bootstrap) I have cut back my webpage to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>zoneshark</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why am I getting the error message?  Does http-server always cause this error?  How can I set up a front end server using nodejs so that this error does not occur (just this simple "hello world" page would be a starting point)?

The server code I am using as an alternative to http-server is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile('./index.html', {root: __dirname});
});

app.get(/^(.+)$/, function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('./' + req.params[0], {root: __dirname});
});

app.listen(80);
```

Another oddity.  From the http-server console, it looks like http-server is serving two resources: /index.html as expected, but also /favicon.ico - which is odd as this is not mentioned anywhere.

The final oddity: this only happens from Chrome.  From IE there is no issue, and no favicon.ico is called for.

In Chrome, I have cleared all browsing data, except autofill form data, passwords and content licences.

Comment: That is a client-side error, so there must be more to your example. The errors refers to something attempting to make a synchronous AJAX request, but your example shows no JS at all. It only comes up in Chrome because it is the only browser that has bothers putting a warning in.

Comment: See `async` in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I have tracked down the issue, and it is within Chrome - more particularly extensions.

The issue is with an extension I have: PropertyWizza v2.0.  Disabling this extension clears the problem.  I will now uninstall it so it doesn't interfere with my development messages.

This was all deduced because I noticed that I had the same problem when accessing any website - including BBC and GitHub for instance - from any computer in my home, as long as I used Chrome.

My advice to anyone starting to debug front-ends for the first time is to check what errors you get on other websites in all your browsers before you begin. This will provide the "control" for your testing.