# Headless Chrome keep popping deprecation

Tags: selenium, synchronous, google-chrome-headless

I am using a selenium headless Chrome on python to scrape a website. This website uses synchronous XMLHttpRequest, which is probably worse than asynchronous, but I don't really care (not my website). Each time my selenium webdriver visits this website, the Chrome deprecation message will be printed in my console:

> "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."

How to stop this message from popping up?

Comment: Have you looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531743/synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thread-is-deprecated-using-nodejs-app-g?rq=1)? It looks like someone else was getting the same warning, albeit in a different context.

Answer (score 3):

This may have already been solved, but as this thread ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47751529/how-do-i-suppress-console-cmd-error-messages-in-python/47798976#47798976)) explains, adding a new argument will help.

```
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced this warning whenever I am using chrome driver with selenium.
Normally, declare driver of chrome as:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)
```

To this, we can pass one more argument, that is, ***options***.
Lets declare it first:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3') ## remove warining
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") ## this will open chrome in backend, hence it will somehow boost processing.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH,options=chrome_options)
```

By this, warning will be removed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm.

`chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')`